# Confirmatory Factor Analysis with Unweighted Least Squares estimation in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am hoping to find someone who has prior experience setting up the R syntax for a CFA with ULS estimation.

The analysis runs, but I just want to see if anyone sees any problems with my setup. The books and articles I have don't provide an example of all the settings available in the cfa function.  Here's the code I've used:

```
d4.fit <- cfa(d3model, data=d3, 
              ordered = c("CR1", "CR2", "CR3", "CR4", "CR5", "CR6", "CR7", 
                          "CA2", "CA3", "CA4", "CA5", "CA6", "P1", "P2",
                          "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P8", "P9"), 
              meanstructure = "default",  conditional.x = "default", 
              fixed.x = "default", orthogonal = FALSE, std.lv = FALSE,
              parameterization = "default", 
              std.ov = FALSE, missing = "default", 
              sample.cov = NULL, sample.cov.rescale = "default",
              sample.mean = NULL, sample.nobs = NULL, ridge = 1e-05, 
              estimator = "ULS", likelihood = "default", 
              information = "default", se = "robust", test = "default",
              bootstrap = NULL, representation = "default",
              do.fit = TRUE, 
              control = list(), WLS.V = NULL, NACOV = NULL,
              zero.add = "default", zero.keep.margins = "default",
              zero.cell.warn = TRUE, start = "default", verbose = FALSE,
              warn = TRUE, debug = FALSE)
```

Sample data (not sure I'm 'hard-coding' the data into the question properly, but here goes - and thanks). Cases are 18 - 27.

```
Sample CR1 CR2 CR3 CR4 CR5 CR6 CR7 CA2 CA3 CA4 CA5 CA6 P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7 P8 P9
18      1   2   5   5   5   4   5   5   1   1   1   1   6  2  4  3  4  5  5  3  5
19      1   7   7   7   7   6   2   1   1   2   1   4   2  2  4  2  1  3  3  4  5
20      1   2   7   1   7   2   1   2   1   1   1   1   1  3  3  3  4  3  4  4  5
21      1   2   4   5   5   6   7   7   1   2   5   3   5  3  2  2  2  2  1  4  5
22      1   5   7   7   5   1   7   5   1   3   6   2   1  4  2  3  5  4  4  5  5
23      1   5   3   6   5   2   4   6   5   6   5   5   5  4  4  2  3  3  2  3  3
24      1   3   1   7   7   1   7   1   1   1   2   1   1  3  4  2  2  3  2  3  2
25      1   3   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   3   5   3   3  4  4  4  2  3  4  2  3
26      1   1   1   7   7   3   7   7   1   3   4   1   2  3  3  3  3  3  3  2  3
27      1   2   3   4   7   3   7   7   1   2   5   2   2  2  3  4  1  1  3  3  1
```

Comment: You can read more about the parameters here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lavaan/versions/0.6-4/topics/cfa

Also, it's hard for us to check your code if we cannot reproduce it. Could you give us some sample data?

Comment: Thanks, Arturo. I prepared a txt data file to add here. Do you know how I would go about uploading it?

Comment: People typically leave around 10 rows of data hardcoded into the question. Example: `sample_data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = sample.int(100))`

Comment: I edited your question slightly. I added a column (P7). I think you were missing it.